# How To Use Formmail's Ini file?

Tags: php, formmail

I'm using tectite.com's Formmail php script. I use a formmail.ini file to obscure email addresses from spammers. That ini file looks like this (nothing else in that file):

```
[special_fields]
recipients = "name@domainnmame.com"
email = "name@domainnmame.com"
```

Note that there are two "special fields," and that they both use the same email address.
This was all working a few days ago, has been for months, then the script stopped working. I determined that the script was corrupt by replacing it with a fresh copy from tectite.com. But then I started getting this error message:

> The following error occurred in FormMail :
> The email address "" is not valid: missing '@'

After extensive troubleshooting, I've found that removing the line 'email = "name@domainnmame.com"' from the ini file solves the error. But I need that option restored.
In replacing the formmail script, it got updated to version 9.26.
Any ideas? Did the latest version change something that keeps my previous ini file from working like it used to?
I tried single quotes. I tried a comma between the two special fields. I tried retyping the addresses. I tried different email addresses. And I tried repeating '[special_fields]', one for each field. No dice... And I can't find any two-line samples on tectite.com

Answer (score 0):

The "email" special field is to hold the address of the person who has filled in your form.

So, it generally makes no sense to set that yourself.

I'd recommend getting your form to work properly without setting the "email" field, and then consider why you're trying to set it.

Perhaps the "email" field is also in your HTML and that's overriding your INI file setting.  But again, that's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a little more insight now. You are correct, using "email" the way I did was probably not what tectite had in mind. I do have an Email field in my form, but that wasn't getting picked up by the script for the From address. I believe that was because I had set the "name" for that field to "Email" (capitol "E"). When I changed that to "email" then the From address was that of the "email" field. But that's not what I need. I need the From address to be a specific address (because of the hosting server's rules, it can't be random addresses).

Comment: I found a Formmail configuration setting that seems to be the solution. It's called FIXED_SENDER (unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation). Unfortunately, that setting doesn't seem to work. So I'm back to square one.

Comment: Try the "mail_options" special field.  Use "FromAddr" feature: https://www.tectite.com/fmdoc/creating_forms.php#mail_options

If that works, you can then move the "mail_options" value to the INI file.  Or, use the EMAIL_ADDRS setting to create an alias for the email address.  https://www.tectite.com/fmdoc/email_addrs.php

Comment: Thanks russellr. That's almost how I solved it (see below). I used mail_options as you mentioned. But instead of using the EMAIL_ADDRS setting in the formmail file, I created an alias and defined that in the ini file. My ini file also contains my recipient emails address setting, so by hiding the FromAddr value there, I keep my two email addresses in the same place. Sometimes they need to change, so in the future I'll be able to easily find both of them.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out. The correct way to manipulate the From address is to use a hidden field, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="FromAddr=name@domainnmame.com" />
```

There are a couple ways to hide the email address from spammers. One, is to create an alias, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="FromAddr=xxx" />
```

And then add the alias definition to the ini file, in my case:

```
[special_fields]
recipients = "name@domainnmame.com"
[email_addresses] 
xxx = "name@domainnmame.com"
```

It's probably possible to put the mail_options in the ini file, but my website has multiple forms on different pages, each with their own unique set of mail_options (I didn't show those other options in my example code). I tried splitting the mail_options: one set in the html code, and another set, with the FromAddr value, in the ini file, but that didn't work. Apparently formmail only honors one line of mail_options.